# Adjust anchor behaviour when the position has been altered by css?

Tags: css, position

How can i adjust with css the anchor so this works even when there is a fixed  element above in the flow that mess things up.

Below is a snippet that demonstrates the issue.

```css
.toolbar {
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="toolbar">my toolbar</div>
<div class='main'>
  <div class='sidebar'>
    <a href="#anchor">scroll to anchor h2</a>
  </div>
  <div class='content'>
    <p>

      Martinus agens illas provincias pro praefectis aerumnas innocentium graviter gemens saepeque obsecrans, ut ab omni culpa inmunibus parceretur, cum non inpetraret, minabatur se discessurum: ut saltem id metuens perquisitor malivolus tandem desineret quieti
      coalitos homines in aperta pericula proiectare. Accedebant enim eius asperitati, ubi inminuta vel laesa amplitudo imperii dicebatur, et iracundae suspicionum quantitati proximorum cruentae blanditiae exaggerantium incidentia et dolere inpendio simulantium,
      si principis periclitetur vita, a cuius salute velut filo pendere statum orbis terrarum fictis vocibus exclamabant. Ex turba vero imae sortis et paupertinae in tabernis aliqui pernoctant vinariis, non nulli velariis umbraculorum theatralium latent,
      quae Campanam imitatus lasciviam Catulus in aedilitate sua suspendit omnium primus; aut pugnaciter aleis certant turpi sono fragosis naribus introrsum reducto spiritu concrepantes; aut quod est studiorum omnium maximum ab ortu lucis ad vesperam
      sole fatiscunt vel pluviis, per minutias aurigarum equorumque praecipua vel delicta scrutantes. Sed ut tum ad senem senex de senectute, sic hoc libro ad amicum amicissimus scripsi de amicitia. Tum est Cato locutus, quo erat nemo fere senior temporibus
      illis, nemo prudentior; nunc Laelius et sapiens (sic enim est habitus) et amicitiae gloria excellens de amicitia loquetur. Tu velim a me animum parumper avertas, Laelium loqui ipsum putes. C. Fannius et Q. Mucius ad socerum veniunt post mortem Africani;
      ab his sermo oritur, respondet Laelius, cuius tota disputatio est de amicitia, quam legens te ipse cognosces. Iam in altera philosophiae parte. quae est quaerendi ac disserendi, quae logikh dicitur, iste vester plane, ut mihi quidem videtur, inermis
      ac nudus est. tollit definitiones, nihil de dividendo ac partiendo docet, non quo modo efficiatur concludaturque ratio tradit, non qua via captiosa solvantur ambigua distinguantur ostendit; iudicia rerum in sensibus ponit, quibus si semel aliquid
      falsi pro vero probatum sit, sublatum esse omne iudicium veri et falsi putat. artinus agens illas provincias pro praefectis aerumnas innocentium graviter gemens saepeque obsecrans, ut ab omni culpa inmunibus parceretur, cum non inpetraret, minabatur
      se discessurum: ut saltem id metuens perquisitor malivolus tandem desineret quieti coalitos homines in aperta pericula proiectare. Accedebant enim eius asperitati, ubi inminuta vel laesa amplitudo imperii dicebatur, et iracundae suspicionum quantitati
      proximorum cruentae blanditiae exaggerantium incidentia et dolere inpendio simulantium, si principis periclitetur vita, a cuius salute velut filo pendere statum orbis terrarum fictis vocibus exclamabant. Ex turba vero imae sortis et paupertinae
      in tabernis aliqui pernoctant vinariis, non nulli velariis umbraculorum theatralium latent, quae Campanam imitatus lasciviam Catulus in aedilitate sua suspendit omnium primus; aut pugnaciter aleis certant turpi sono fragosis naribus introrsum reducto
      spiritu concrepantes; aut quod est studiorum omnium maximum ab ortu lucis ad vesperam sole fatiscunt vel pluviis, per minutias aurigarum equorumque praecipua vel delicta scrutantes. Sed ut tum ad senem senex de senectute, sic hoc libro ad amicum
      amicissimus scripsi de amicitia. Tum est Cato locutus, quo erat nemo fere senior temporibus illis, nemo prudentior; nunc Laelius et sapiens (sic enim est habitus) et amicitiae gloria excellens de amicitia loquetur. Tu velim a me animum parumper
      avertas, Laelium loqui ipsum putes. C. Fannius et Q. Mucius ad socerum veniunt post mortem Africani; ab his sermo oritur, respondet Laelius, cuius tota disputatio est de amicitia, quam legens te ipse cognosces. Iam in altera philosophiae parte.
      quae est quaerendi ac disserendi, quae logikh dicitur, iste vester plane, ut mihi quidem videtur, inermis ac nudus est. tollit definitiones, nihil de dividendo ac partiendo docet, non quo modo efficiatur concludaturque ratio tradit, non qua via
      captiosa solvantur ambigua distinguantur ostendit; iudicia rerum in sensibus ponit, quibus si semel aliquid falsi pro vero probatum sit, sublatum esse omne iudicium veri et falsi putat. artinus agens illas provincias pro praefectis aerumnas innocentium
      graviter gemens saepeque obsecrans, ut ab omni culpa inmunibus parceretur, cum non inpetraret, minabatur se discessurum: ut saltem id metuens perquisitor malivolus tandem desineret quieti coalitos homines in aperta pericula proiectare. Accedebant
      enim eius asperitati, ubi inminuta vel laesa amplitudo imperii dicebatur, et iracundae suspicionum quantitati proximorum cruentae blanditiae exaggerantium incidentia et dolere inpendio simulantium, si principis periclitetur vita, a cuius salute
      velut filo pendere statum orbis terrarum fictis vocibus exclamabant. Ex turba vero imae sortis et paupertinae in tabernis aliqui pernoctant vinariis, non nulli velariis umbraculorum theatralium latent, quae Campanam imitatus lasciviam Catulus in
      aedilitate sua suspendit omnium primus; aut pugnaciter aleis certant turpi sono fragosis naribus introrsum reducto spiritu concrepantes; aut quod est studiorum omnium maximum ab ortu lucis ad vesperam sole fatiscunt vel pluviis, per minutias aurigarum
      equorumque praecipua vel delicta scrutantes. Sed ut tum ad senem senex de senectute, sic hoc libro ad amicum amicissimus scripsi de amicitia. Tum est Cato locutus, quo erat nemo fere senior temporibus illis, nemo prudentior; nunc Laelius et sapiens
      (sic enim est habitus) et amicitiae gloria excellens de amicitia loquetur. Tu velim a me animum parumper avertas, Laelium loqui ipsum putes. C. Fannius et Q. Mucius ad socerum veniunt post mortem Africani; ab his sermo oritur, respondet Laelius,
      cuius tota disputatio est de amicitia, quam legens te ipse cognosces. Iam in altera philosophiae parte. quae est quaerendi ac disserendi, quae logikh dicitur, iste vester plane, ut mihi quidem videtur, inermis ac nudus est. tollit definitiones,
      nihil de dividendo ac partiendo docet, non quo modo efficiatur concludaturque ratio tradit, non qua via captiosa solvantur ambigua distinguantur ostendit; iudicia rerum in sensibus ponit, quibus si semel aliquid falsi pro vero probatum sit, sublatum
      esse omne iudicium veri et falsi putat. artinus agens illas provincias pro praefectis aerumnas innocentium graviter gemens saepeque obsecrans, ut ab omni culpa inmunibus parceretur, cum non inpetraret, minabatur se discessurum: ut saltem id metuens
      perquisitor malivolus tandem desineret quieti coalitos homines in aperta pericula proiectare. Accedebant enim eius asperitati, ubi inminuta vel laesa amplitudo imperii dicebatur, et iracundae suspicionum quantitati proximorum cruentae blanditiae
      exaggerantium incidentia et dolere inpendio simulantium, si principis periclitetur vita, a cuius salute velut filo pendere statum orbis terrarum fictis vocibus exclamabant. Ex turba vero imae sortis et paupertinae in tabernis aliqui pernoctant vinariis,
      non nulli velariis umbraculorum theatralium latent, quae Campanam imitatus lasciviam Catulus in aedilitate sua suspendit omnium primus; aut pugnaciter aleis certant turpi sono fragosis naribus introrsum reducto spiritu concrepantes; aut quod est
      studiorum omnium maximum ab ortu lucis ad vesperam sole fatiscunt vel pluviis, per minutias aurigarum equorumque praecipua vel delicta scrutantes. Sed ut tum ad senem senex de senectute, sic hoc libro ad amicum amicissimus scripsi de amicitia. Tum
      est Cato locutus, quo erat nemo fere senior temporibus illis, nemo prudentior; nunc Laelius et sapiens (sic enim est habitus) et amicitiae gloria excellens de amicitia loquetur. Tu velim a me animum parumper avertas, Laelium loqui ipsum putes. C.
      Fannius et Q. Mucius ad socerum veniunt post mortem Africani; ab his sermo oritur, respondet Laelius, cuius tota disputatio est de amicitia, quam legens te ipse cognosces. Iam in altera philosophiae parte. quae est quaerendi ac disserendi, quae
      logikh dicitur, iste vester plane, ut mihi quidem videtur, inermis ac nudus est. tollit definitiones, nihil de dividendo ac partiendo docet, non quo modo efficiatur concludaturque ratio tradit, non qua via captiosa solvantur ambigua distinguantur
      ostendit; iudicia rerum in sensibus ponit, quibus si semel aliquid falsi pro vero probatum sit, sublatum esse omne iudicium veri et falsi putat.
    </p>
    <h2 id="anchor">my title</h2>
    <p>

      Martinus agens illas provincias pro praefectis aerumnas innocentium graviter gemens saepeque obsecrans, ut ab omni culpa inmunibus parceretur, cum non inpetraret, minabatur se discessurum: ut saltem id metuens perquisitor malivolus tandem desineret quieti
      coalitos homines in aperta pericula proiectare. Accedebant enim eius asperitati, ubi inminuta vel laesa amplitudo imperii dicebatur, et iracundae suspicionum quantitati proximorum cruentae blanditiae exaggerantium incidentia et dolere inpendio simulantium,
      si principis periclitetur vita, a cuius salute velut filo pendere statum orbis terrarum fictis vocibus exclamabant. Ex turba vero imae sortis et paupertinae in tabernis aliqui pernoctant vinariis, non nulli velariis umbraculorum theatralium latent,
      quae Campanam imitatus lasciviam Catulus in aedilitate sua suspendit omnium primus; aut pugnaciter aleis certant turpi sono fragosis naribus introrsum reducto spiritu concrepantes; aut quod est studiorum omnium maximum ab ortu lucis ad vesperam
      sole fatiscunt vel pluviis, per minutias aurigarum equorumque praecipua vel delicta scrutantes. Sed ut tum ad senem senex de senectute, sic hoc libro ad amicum amicissimus scripsi de amicitia. Tum est Cato locutus, quo erat nemo fere senior temporibus
      illis, nemo prudentior; nunc Laelius et sapiens (sic enim est habitus) et amicitiae gloria excellens de amicitia loquetur. Tu velim a me animum parumper avertas, Laelium loqui ipsum putes. C. Fannius et Q. Mucius ad socerum veniunt post mortem Africani;
      ab his sermo oritur, respondet Laelius, cuius tota disputatio est de amicitia, quam legens te ipse cognosces. Iam in altera philosophiae parte. quae est quaerendi ac disserendi, quae logikh dicitur, iste vester plane, ut mihi quidem videtur, inermis
      ac nudus est. tollit definitiones, nihil de dividendo ac partiendo docet, non quo modo efficiatur concludaturque ratio tradit, non qua via captiosa solvantur ambigua distinguantur ostendit; iudicia rerum in sensibus ponit, quibus si semel aliquid
      falsi pro vero probatum sit, sublatum esse omne iudicium veri et falsi putat. artinus agens illas provincias pro praefectis aerumnas innocentium graviter gemens saepeque obsecrans, ut ab omni culpa inmunibus parceretur, cum non inpetraret, minabatur
      se discessurum: ut saltem id metuens perquisitor malivolus tandem desineret quieti coalitos homines in aperta pericula proiectare. Accedebant enim eius asperitati, ubi inminuta vel laesa amplitudo imperii dicebatur, et iracundae suspicionum quantitati
      proximorum cruentae blanditiae exaggerantium incidentia et dolere inpendio simulantium, si principis periclitetur vita, a cuius salute velut filo pendere statum orbis terrarum fictis vocibus exclamabant. Ex turba vero imae sortis et paupertinae
      in tabernis aliqui pernoctant vinariis, non nulli velariis umbraculorum theatralium latent, quae Campanam imitatus lasciviam Catulus in aedilitate sua suspendit omnium primus; aut pugnaciter aleis certant turpi sono fragosis naribus introrsum reducto
      spiritu concrepantes; aut quod est studiorum omnium maximum ab ortu lucis ad vesperam sole fatiscunt vel pluviis, per minutias aurigarum equorumque praecipua vel delicta scrutantes. Sed ut tum ad senem senex de senectute, sic hoc libro ad amicum
      amicissimus scripsi de amicitia. Tum est Cato locutus, quo erat nemo fere senior temporibus illis, nemo prudentior; nunc Laelius et sapiens (sic enim est habitus) et amicitiae gloria excellens de amicitia loquetur. Tu velim a me animum parumper
      avertas, Laelium loqui ipsum putes. C. Fannius et Q. Mucius ad socerum veniunt post mortem Africani; ab his sermo oritur, respondet Laelius, cuius tota disputatio est de amicitia, quam legens te ipse cognosces. Iam in altera philosophiae parte.
      quae est quaerendi ac disserendi, quae logikh dicitur, iste vester plane, ut mihi quidem videtur, inermis ac nudus est. tollit definitiones, nihil de dividendo ac partiendo docet, non quo modo efficiatur concludaturque ratio tradit, non qua via
      captiosa solvantur ambigua distinguantur ostendit; iudicia rerum in sensibus ponit, quibus si semel aliquid falsi pro vero probatum sit, sublatum esse omne iudicium veri et falsi putat. artinus agens illas provincias pro praefectis aerumnas innocentium
      graviter gemens saepeque obsecrans, ut ab omni culpa inmunibus parceretur, cum non inpetraret, minabatur se discessurum: ut saltem id metuens perquisitor malivolus tandem desineret quieti coalitos homines in aperta pericula proiectare. Accedebant
      enim eius asperitati, ubi inminuta vel laesa amplitudo imperii dicebatur, et iracundae suspicionum quantitati proximorum cruentae blanditiae exaggerantium incidentia et dolere inpendio simulantium, si principis periclitetur vita, a cuius salute
      velut filo pendere statum orbis terrarum fictis vocibus exclamabant. Ex turba vero imae sortis et paupertinae in tabernis aliqui pernoctant vinariis, non nulli velariis umbraculorum theatralium latent, quae Campanam imitatus lasciviam Catulus in
      aedilitate sua suspendit omnium primus; aut pugnaciter aleis certant turpi sono fragosis naribus introrsum reducto spiritu concrepantes; aut quod est studiorum omnium maximum ab ortu lucis ad vesperam sole fatiscunt vel pluviis, per minutias aurigarum
      equorumque praecipua vel delicta scrutantes. Sed ut tum ad senem senex de senectute, sic hoc libro ad amicum amicissimus scripsi de amicitia. Tum est Cato locutus, quo erat nemo fere senior temporibus illis, nemo prudentior; nunc Laelius et sapiens
      (sic enim est habitus) et amicitiae gloria excellens de amicitia loquetur. Tu velim a me animum parumper avertas, Laelium loqui ipsum putes. C. Fannius et Q. Mucius ad socerum veniunt post mortem Africani; ab his sermo oritur, respondet Laelius,
      cuius tota disputatio est de amicitia, quam legens te ipse cognosces. Iam in altera philosophiae parte. quae est quaerendi ac disserendi, quae logikh dicitur, iste vester plane, ut mihi quidem videtur, inermis ac nudus est. tollit definitiones,
      nihil de dividendo ac partiendo docet, non quo modo efficiatur concludaturque ratio tradit, non qua via captiosa solvantur ambigua distinguantur ostendit; iudicia rerum in sensibus ponit, quibus si semel aliquid falsi pro vero probatum sit, sublatum
      esse omne iudicium veri et falsi putat. artinus agens illas provincias pro praefectis aerumnas innocentium graviter gemens saepeque obsecrans, ut ab omni culpa inmunibus parceretur, cum non inpetraret, minabatur se discessurum: ut saltem id metuens
      perquisitor malivolus tandem desineret quieti coalitos homines in aperta pericula proiectare. Accedebant enim eius asperitati, ubi inminuta vel laesa amplitudo imperii dicebatur, et iracundae suspicionum quantitati proximorum cruentae blanditiae
      exaggerantium incidentia et dolere inpendio simulantium, si principis periclitetur vita, a cuius salute velut filo pendere statum orbis terrarum fictis vocibus exclamabant. Ex turba vero imae sortis et paupertinae in tabernis aliqui pernoctant vinariis,
      non nulli velariis umbraculorum theatralium latent, quae Campanam imitatus lasciviam Catulus in aedilitate sua suspendit omnium primus; aut pugnaciter aleis certant turpi sono fragosis naribus introrsum reducto spiritu concrepantes; aut quod est
      studiorum omnium maximum ab ortu lucis ad vesperam sole fatiscunt vel pluviis, per minutias aurigarum equorumque praecipua vel delicta scrutantes. Sed ut tum ad senem senex de senectute, sic hoc libro ad amicum amicissimus scripsi de amicitia. Tum
      est Cato locutus, quo erat nemo fere senior temporibus illis, nemo prudentior; nunc Laelius et sapiens (sic enim est habitus) et amicitiae gloria excellens de amicitia loquetur. Tu velim a me animum parumper avertas, Laelium loqui ipsum putes. C.
      Fannius et Q. Mucius ad socerum veniunt post mortem Africani; ab his sermo oritur, respondet Laelius, cuius tota disputatio est de amicitia, quam legens te ipse cognosces. Iam in altera philosophiae parte. quae est quaerendi ac disserendi, quae
      logikh dicitur, iste vester plane, ut mihi quidem videtur, inermis ac nudus est. tollit definitiones, nihil de dividendo ac partiendo docet, non quo modo efficiatur concludaturque ratio tradit, non qua via captiosa solvantur ambigua distinguantur
      ostendit; iudicia rerum in sensibus ponit, quibus si semel aliquid falsi pro vero probatum sit, sublatum esse omne iudicium veri et falsi putat.
    </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Alternatively, you can see the same issue in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/matoeil/pen/ddYRQG)

Drupal add a padding top to the body when the fixed toolbar is on.
How can i adjust the h2 anchor scroll with or without the toolbar ?

Comment: "mess things up" is the same as "doesn't work". Are we meant to guess?

Comment: the scroll is not at the anchor position but lower down because of that fixed element height

Comment: Hi. No need to use codepen for demonstration of HTML/CSS issues. We have the tooling right here in SO. I edited your post accordingly.